# Negative Timestamp Java

Tags: java, android

I have wierdo problem with timestamp in Java/Android

```
    Date inputDate = null;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm dd/MM/yyyy");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    Log.e("DateH:D", hour+" "+day);
    try {
        inputDate = sdf.parse(hour + " " + day);
        Date currentDate = new Date();
        Log.e("InputDate", inputDate.toString());
        Log.e("InputDate",inputDate.getTime()+"");
        Log.e("CurrentDate", currentDate.toString());
        Log.e("CurrentDate",currentDate.getTime()+"");
        if (!inputDate.after(currentDate) ){
            //TODO change this string
            hourField.setError("Date from past");
            return false;
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        Log.e("DateParser" , e.getLocalizedMessage);
        return false;
    }
```

Example output for this is:

```
DateH:D: 12:33 15/09/16
E/InputDate: Tue Sep 15 14:33:00 CET 16
E/InputDate: -61640134020000
E/InputDate: Tue Sep 15 14:33:00 CET 16
E/CurrentDate: Thu Sep 15 11:38:43 CEST 2016
E/CurrentDate: 1473932323198
```

So non-timestamp representation of date is correct but timestamp is wrong. How it's possible? What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: The year 16 is 2000 years ago...

Comment: Thank You. I needed fresh eye to see my code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `yy` to parse 2-digit years.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm dd/MM/yy");
```

Comment: Yep as Jesper noticed i had wrong pattern. Thank you for help

Comment: Is not good only two digits for the year 2020 = 20?

Answer (score 1):

The [`getTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime--) method of `Date`:

> Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT
>   represented by this Date object.

Since the year you specified is **year 16,** the negative result makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The starting date for epoch milis is Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT. Any datetime before that is negative in epoch milis.